# Join clause by inverseJoinColumn

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I have an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`petition`")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Petition extends Auditable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3234225397035713824L;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "petition_selected_school", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "petition_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "school_id",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private List<School> selectedSchools;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "petition_basic_school", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "petition_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "school_id",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private List<School> fullBasicSchoolList;

}
```

I'm trying generate sql like this

```
SELECT
p.id, s.*, b.*
FROM petition p JOIN petition_selected_school s ON p.id = s.petition_id
  LEFT JOIN petition_basic_school b ON p.id = b.petition_id AND s.school_id = b.school_id
WHERE s.petition_id = 244
```

But JPA give me not the same...

```
SELECT
  petition0_.id, selectedsc1_.*, fullbasics3_.*
FROM "petition" petition0_ INNER JOIN petition_selected_school selectedsc1_ ON petition0_.id = selectedsc1_.petition_id
  INNER JOIN "school" school2_ ON selectedsc1_.school_id = school2_.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN petition_basic_school fullbasics3_ ON petition0_.id = fullbasics3_.petition_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "school" school4_ ON fullbasics3_.school_id = school4_.id AND (school4_.id = school2_.id)
WHERE petition0_.id = 244
```

There is how i'm trying to build query

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Petition> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Petition.class);
Root root = criteriaQuery.from(Petition.class);
ListJoin join = root.joinList("selectedSchools");
ListJoin join2 = root.joinList("fullBasicSchoolList", JoinType.LEFT);
```

I just want to make a join by inverseJoinColumns: s.school_id = b.school_id
is it possible with criteria builder?
Then i'd like to check if join by fullBasicSchoolList is NULL